# mysqlimport: Error: 1045, Access denied 

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1045, mysqlimport

Does anyone know why I get this error when running mysqlimport?

```
mysqlimport -u someone -pwhatever --columns=a,b,c,d,e bar /var/tmp/baz.sql
mysqlimport: Error: 1045, Access denied for user 'someone'@'%' (using password: YES), when using table: baz
```

However...

```
mysql -u someone -pwhatever
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 199
Server version: 5.1.41-3ubuntu12.10 (Ubuntu)

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> show grants;
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for someone@%                                                                                   |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'someone'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*BLAHBLAHBLAH' |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `bar`.* TO 'someone'@'%'                                          |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

OK, it turns out that the FILE privilege is a "global" privilege, which apparently means you can't selectively enable it on certain databases, tables. etc. That's why my previous grant statement on bar.* had no effect:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `bar`.* TO 'someone'@'%'
```

You need to grant FILE privileges on `*.*`:

```
GRANT FILE ON *.* to 'someone'@'%';
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: If you get 'ERROR 1221 (HY000): Incorrect usage of DB GRANT and GLOBAL PRIVILEGES', after setting different parameters, revert back to what this answer shows: "GRANT FILE ON *.* to user@localhost;" - "the FILE privileges are global and cannot be applied to a single database"

Answer (score 33):

You can avoid the need for the extra privileges by using the --local parameter to mysqlimport:

```
--local, -L

           Read input files locally from the client host.
```

Comment: Worked for me, and IMHO a much better approach than granting an important global permission to one user

Comment: This still works on MySQL 8.0 e.g. `mysql -L -f database < dump.sql` and you don't need to use `mysqlimport` command either.

Answer (score 13):

Some would instead opt for this command, skipping the extra FILE grant.

`mysql -u username -p <yourdbname> < yourfile.sql`

Comment: how do i get this to work on importing a csv file? Do i just rewrite the csv file in a .sql format and then imprt it? or can I use something like http://stackoverflow.com/a/18469353/2392358 `mysqlimport`

Comment: @HattrickNZ well that command is only if you have statements in your .sql file. If you have .csv I guess you would have to do something different, like posted in your link.

Answer (score 6):

mysqlimport is a command-line interface to the LOAD DATA INFILE statement, for which you need the 'FILE' privilege (server level).

From [LOAD DATA INFILE syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html):

```
Also, to use LOAD DATA INFILE on server files, you must have the FILE privilege.
```

Comment: So "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES" doesn't include the FILE privilege?

Comment: You're granting ALL PRIVILEGES at the database level, whereas the FILE privilege is at the server level.

Comment: Ah yes, I just figured that out. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

#### TLDR: Use the `--set-gtid-purged=OFF` Arg in MySQLDump

When doing `mysqldump -u username -p` to create the file you're going to import elsewhere, throw in the argument of `--set-gtid-purged=OFF`.

GTIDs are needed for replication, and probably don't apply to what you're doing if you just want to copy/paste DB 1 to DB 2.

#### General Debugging Help

My debugging process here was a little bit different than what others have done.  I suggest this to debug: Change your `.sql` to the simplest possible thing, maybe just one single `CREATE TABLE` statement, and see if it runs.

If it runs, then these are things that you want to remove from your SQL import file:

- Any line setting `@@GLOBAL.GTID`.
- `SET @MYSQLDUMP_TEMP_LOG_BIN = @@SESSION.SQL_LOG_BIN;`
- `SET @@SESSION.SQL_LOG_BIN= 0;`
- `SET @@SESSION.SQL_LOG_BIN = @MYSQLDUMP_TEMP_LOG_BIN;`

As you can see, it's a lot of [GTID stuff](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-gtids-concepts.html), which is transaction ID info used for doing replication.  So, these are important when doing server replication, but not when doing basically a copy-paste of one DB to another DB, and in that case we can drop them.