# Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost'

Tags: mysql

I've looked everywhere an cannot seem to find a fix for this issue, despite tons of articles on it. Anyway, I'm attempting the following command

```
mysqldump -hlocalhost -uroot -p mydb mytable > myexportedtable.sql
```

This will occasionally result in the following error

```
mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' <using password:NO> when trying to connect
```

This is baffling for two reasons. One - I am specifying a root user in my command however it assumes I'm ODBC. Two - I only get this error occasionally. (more often than not). I am able to authenticate to the mysql interactive shell when specifying root but keep getting this error with mySQL dump. Any insight is greatly appreciated as I've been trouble shooting this for days now.

Comment: Are you running this as the "ODBC" user? From localhost?

Comment: I'm running from localhost

Comment: Are you omitting the space between `-u` and `root` or is just a typo in your question?

Comment: Also, note that the default host is localhost, so you don't actually need to specify it.

Comment: Test ODBC connection from ODBC Manager in Control Panel. Probably it has bad configuration there. Try using DSN.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Type in the command manually. Sometimes copying and pasting the command changes the hyphen character (-). It is ignoring the username because it literally doesn't recognize a -u.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to happen when you connect with the wrong user to the database, wrong password usage or when you connect from the wrong host or over the socket/port when you are not allowed to.

I suggest checking the access privileges of the user like:

```
mysql> SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user WHERE user = 'jake';
mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR 'jake'@'localhost';
```

Perhaps also take a look at [mysqlimport: Error: 1045, Access denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6837061/mysqlimport-error-1045-access-denied) , which helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the password in quotes.

Using MySQL 8 and Powershell 7, I had this same no access problem problem with mysqldump. It turned out I needed to enclose my password in quotes since it had a period in it. Powershell 7, with its better colors,made it obvious since the font color changed midway thru the password.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).