# importing a csv file into mysql from the command line using mysqlimport command

Tags: mysql, csv

How to import a csv file into mysql from the command line using mysqlimport command, so thats without going into mysql.?

I am trying to use this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18469353/2392358)

to import a csv file into mysql from the command line

```
root@678cf3cd1587:/home# mysqlimport --columns='head -n 1 discounts.csv' --ignore-lines=1 temp discounts.csv -u root -p
Enter password:
mysqlimport: Error: 1064, You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-n 1 discounts.csv)' at line 1, when using table: discounts
root@678cf3cd1587:/home#
```

But I cannot get it to work can anyone advise what I am doing wrong?

this is what my file looks like

```
root@678cf3cd1587:/var/lib/mysql-files# cat discounts.csv
id,title,expired_date,amount
1,"1Spring Break ",20140401,20
2,"2Spring Break ",20140401,20
3,"3Spring Break ",20140401,20
4,"3Spring Break ",20140401,20
5,"3Spring Break ",20140401,20
6,"3Spring Break ",20140401,20
7,"3Spring Break ",20140401,20
```

And this is what my mysql looks like:

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
| temp               |
+--------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> use temp
Database changed
mysql> show tables;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

**NOTE** I am running mysql in a docker container which I can give more details on if required
There is duplicates of this question but I think mine is specific.

**EDIT1**

I had tried the different single-quote ' double-quote " and backtick  `. although the back tick gave a different error. does that help?

```
root@678cf3cd1587:/home# mysqlimport --columns='head -n 1 discounts.csv' --ignore-lines=1 temp discounts.csv -u root -p
Enter password:
mysqlimport: Error: 1064, You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-n 1 discounts.csv)' at line 1, when using table: discounts
root@678cf3cd1587:/home# mysqlimport --columns="head -n 1 discounts.csv" --ignore-lines=1 temp discounts.csv -u root -p
Enter password:
mysqlimport: Error: 1064, You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-n 1 discounts.csv)' at line 1, when using table: discounts
root@678cf3cd1587:/home# mysqlimport --columns=`head -n 1 discounts.csv` --ignore-lines=1 temp discounts.csv -u root -p
Enter password:
mysqlimport: Error: 1049 Unknown database 'date,amount'
```

**EDIT2**

If i do it without a table created I get `Error: 1146, Table 'temp.discounts' doesn't exist, when using table: discounts`

```
root@678cf3cd1587:/var/lib/mysql-files# mysqlimport temp /var/lib/mysql-files/discounts.csv -u root -p --columns=`head -n 1 /var/lib/mysql-files/discounts.csv` --ignore-lines=1
Enter password:
mysqlimport: Error: 1146, Table 'temp.discounts' doesn't exist, when using table: discounts
```

If i then create the table and then try again

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE discounts (
    ->   id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->   title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    ->   expired_date DATE NOT NULL,
    ->   amount DECIMAL(10,2) NULL,
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (id)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

mysql>
mysql>
mysql>
mysql> show tables;
+----------------+
| Tables_in_temp |
+----------------+
| discounts      |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from discounts;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

I get the following error `Error: 1265, Data truncated for column 'id' at row 1, when using table: discounts`

```
root@678cf3cd1587:/var/lib/mysql-files# mysqlimport temp /var/lib/mysql-files/discounts.csv -u root -p --columns=`head -n 1 /var/lib/mysql-files/discounts.csv` --ignore-lines=1
Enter password:
mysqlimport: Error: 1265, Data truncated for column 'id' at row 1, when using table: discounts
root@678cf3cd1587:/var/lib/mysql-files#
```

I am using `/var/lib/mysql-files/discounts.csv` explicitly because, if i understand correctly, this is the only directory i can import files from with `secure_file_priv`

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv";
+------------------+-----------------------+
| Variable_name    | Value                 |
+------------------+-----------------------+
| secure_file_priv | /var/lib/mysql-files/ |
+------------------+-----------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql>
```

**EDIT3**

I got this to work 
`` mysqlimport --columns="`head -n 1 /var/lib/mysql-files/discounts.csv`" --ignore-lines=1 temp /var/lib/mysql-files/discounts.csv -u root -p --fields-terminated-by=','  --fields-optionally-enclosed-by='"' ``

```
root@678cf3cd1587:/home# mysqlimport --columns="`head -n 1 /var/lib/mysql-files/discounts.csv`" --ignore-lines=1 temp /var/lib/mysql-files/discounts.csv -u root -p --fields-terminated-by=','  --fields-optionally-enclosed-by='"'
Enter password:
temp.discounts: Records: 7  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0
root@678cf3cd1587:/home#
root@678cf3cd1587:/home# cat /var/lib/mysql-files/discounts.csv
id,title,expired_date,amount
1,"1Spring Break ",20140401,20
2,"2Spring Break ",20140401,20
3,"3Spring Break ",20140401,20
4,"3Spring Break ",20140401,20
5,"3Spring Break ",20140401,20
6,"3Spring Break ",20140401,20
7,"3Spring Break ",20140401,20
```

But I had to create the table first in my sql, as above.

```
CREATE TABLE discounts (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  expired_date DATE NOT NULL,
  amount DECIMAL(10,2) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

I also had to use this file `/var/lib/mysql-files/discounts.csv` as `secure_file_priv` is set so that I can only load files from this directory, as I understand it.

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv";
+------------------+-----------------------+
| Variable_name    | Value                 |
+------------------+-----------------------+
| secure_file_priv | /var/lib/mysql-files/ |
+------------------+-----------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: Seems you want backticks surround the shell call to `head`.

Comment: tks see Edit1 I had tried that but still could not work it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the space in "expired date" may be tripping you up. On the command line you'll need to quote the `--columns` argument, while keeping the backticks.

```
mysqlimport --columns="`head -n 1 discounts.csv`" \
--ignore-lines=1 temp discounts.csv -u root -p
```

Is the table column name actually "expired date" with the space? If so you'll need to account for that in your csv file with backticks.

```
id,title,`expired date`,amount
```

Also, ensure you specify the format of the file if it differs from the default of

> FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' ENCLOSED BY '' ESCAPED BY '\' LINES
>   TERMINATED BY '\n' STARTING BY ''

In your case,

```
--fields-terminated-by=','  --fields-optionally-enclosed-by='"'
```

Comment: tks and sorry but i had spotted that, I updated the contents of discounts.csv to be `expired_date` which should not trip me up  I have updated my question, but still having issues, see edit3.

Comment: tks, got it to work, see edit 3 in my question. to get it to work I had to create the table called `discounts` with the headers, in mysql first. is there away around this? I was hoping to be able to do it all from the command line.

Comment: The table will need to exist before you can load data into it. mysqlimport is just a data loading tool. If you put the table creation statement in a file called discounts.sql, you could run that from the command line to create the table. `mysql -u root -p temp < discounts.sql` You would only run that once though, as the table only needs to be created one time.