# How to create SQL database for ICD-10 Codes?

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008-r2

I have an XML file but i think it is not processable. What should I do to create database for ICD-10 disease codes.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  This question is unclear/too broad as written.  What __specific__ technical challenge are you facing, and what concrete steps have you taken to overcome it?  Where are you getting hung up?

Comment: [How do I ask a **good** question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.
Actually I want to create a database for ICD Codes in sql server.
XML files are there but i don't know weather xml files are usable for sql database creation or how .

Comment: Thank you @marc_s.
Appreciated. :)

Comment: Your current questions is too open-ended, too broad - you need to give us more concrete, detailed information - what are you trying to do? What is the point where you run into problems? As it stands, it's just too broad - entire books have been written on the topic - can't *answer* this in a few paragraphs and a few code lines

Comment: @DanField , waiting for your kind response?

Comment: ICD-10 Codes are World Health Organization's Codes for identifying diseases.
I want to create a database for ICD-10 Codes. But it has approx 68000 codes. How to create sql database easily for ICD-10 Codes ?

Comment: @KhalidZubair, even if your question is "How do I create a database schema from an XML file", that's still too broad/open ended.  A good part of my consulting work revolves around answering that question ;)

Comment: How to send a rar file in stack overflow ?
I'll send you that xml file. Have a look . @DanField :)

Comment: <sectionIndex>
      <sectionRef first="A00" last="A09" id="A00-A09">
         Intestinal infectious diseases
      </sectionRef>
      <sectionRef first="A15" last="A19" id="A15-A19">
         Tuberculosis
      </sectionRef>
</sectionIndex>

This is a part of code . @DanField

Comment: @KhalidZubair, my last comment was meant to indicate that this is a question I would expect to get paid to answer, as it stands right now.  Check up on marc_s's link if you want to come up with a StackOverflow appropriate question. If you're looking for professional services, contact me via my email in my profile.

Comment: Okay. Thank you. :) @DanField

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Khalid!

I'm also was looking for an answer to a similar question. So I've found answer like this - [ICD10 MYSQL TABLES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860153/icd10-mysql-tables/15461757#15461757)

So you have to choose not ICD-10 (2016) XML file but ICD-10 2010 version with  `Plain text tabular.`

Next I've imported this text file in my dbForge Studio for MySQL. And it all works!

Steps for import ICD-10 by SQL you could find in the source post  http://fash7y.wordpress.com/2012/04/05/import-icd-10-to-mysql-database/

Answer (score 0):

Using python to create a csv file could help. E.g.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
import csv
import sys
import os

tree = ET.parse(sys.argv[1])
root = tree.getroot() 

fieldnames = ['code', 'description']
spamwriter = csv.writer(sys.stdout, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

spamwriter.writerow(fieldnames)
for code in root.findall(".//diag"):
    spamwriter.writerow([code.find("./name").text.encode('utf-8').strip(), code.find("./desc").text.encode('utf-8').strip()])
```

The end result

```
code,description
A00,Cholera
A00.0,"Cholera due to Vibrio cholerae 01, biovar cholerae"
A00.1,"Cholera due to Vibrio cholerae 01, biovar eltor"
A00.9,"Cholera, unspecified"
A01,Typhoid and paratyphoid fevers
...
```

Usage

```
python icd102csv.py ICD10CM_2020_Full_Tabular.xml > icd10-codes-2020.csv
```

[Then import into MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6605783/65694)

ICD-10 Data source: ftp://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/Health_Statistics/NCHS/Publications/ICD10CM/2020