# How to quickly import a large CSV file into database

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, xampp, localhost

I have a 300MB CSV file and I need to import it to my localhost database. I have changed upload_max_filesize and post_max_size in php.ini.

The problem is that it is taking a very long time to complete the import.

I want to know how I can do it faster. It should not take this long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upload it to the server and use the command-line.  This will reduce any inefficiencies created by having php, the web server, the web client, and the internet connection to you sitting on top of the actual import.

[Importing a csv into mysql via command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605765/importing-a-csv-into-mysql-via-command-line)

Comment: Alternatively, you could upload the file (through SFTP, SCP, etc) to a particular folder on your webserver and use the phpMyAdmin "UploadDir" directive to point to the file. But I do agree that the command line is the best solution when available. See http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_UploadDir for details