# memory size exceeds in phpexcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have a huge file that I would like to read so I can fill my mysql database. I tried to use the PHPExcel library but I get an error when I want to load my file :

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 22 bytes) in C:\Wamp\www\Classes\PHPExcel\Worksheet.php on
>   line 964

I have already increased the value of the `memory_limit` in the `php.ini` file but it's still not enough. My Excel file is more than 60 MB (5 109 719 cells).

Anybody have an idea how to solve this problem ?

Comment: Try to set memory limit **ini_set('memory_limit','2048M'); ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes** inside the function where you reads the excel.

`function reader(){ini_set('memory_limit','2048M');ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //write your logic here
}`

Comment: Have you used any of the documented methods for reducing memory usage for large files? Cell caching? Chunked loading?

Answer (score 0):

Reading 5 million cells using PHPExcel is a tricky problem. You can try using the cell caching or chunked loading techniques that Mark mentioned. Take a look at the documentation here: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/04-Configuration-Settings.md

I also tried reading millions of cells with PHPExcel, using these techniques but it then becomes a performance problem (instead of a memory problem). Reading so many cells take forever. So alternatively, you can try using Spout: https://github.com/box/spout. Reading 5 millions cells should only require a few MB of memory and take 20 to 40 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

If your don't have some special functions its much better to export your file as CSV and import it directly to MySQL. 5 Million cells are a lot and that would take too long time with PHP.

[Importing a csv into mysql via command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605765/importing-a-csv-into-mysql-via-command-line)

I'm not a big Java fan but for that you get a good lib.

https://poi.apache.org/

POI perform good on big files and is working better than PHP. If you can't convert your file to CSV and read it. You should take a look at POI.