# Importing certain columns from csv into mysql via command line

Tags: mysql, sql, csv

I have a csv file and want to import part of it into my Mysql database. 
From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605765/importing-a-csv-into-mysql-via-command-line), I tried this command in my Mysql command line

```
 load data local infile 'mycsv.csv’ into table mytable fields terminated by ',' enclosed by '"' lines terminated by '\n' (entity_ticker,harvested_at, entity_sector,entity_competitors,story_type,story_source,event,entity_sentiment,event_sentiment,event_relevance,entity_relevance,entity_industry)
```

Those in bracket is the columns I want to put in my table. The order is same to my table but not same to csv file.

And the mysql didn't do anything like this:

```
mysql>  load data local infile '2013first1000.csv’ into table news_dataset fields terminated by ',' enclosed by '"' lines terminated by '\n' (entity_ticker,harvested_at, entity_sector,entity_competitors,story_type,story_source,event,entity_sentiment,event_sentiment,event_relevance,entity_relevance,entity_industry)
    "> 
    "> 
    "> 
    ">
```

This is the first two row of my file opened in txt:

> signal_id,story_id,story_group_id,new_story_group,story_group_count,source_id,author_id,story_type,story_source,templated_story_score,story_traffic,story_group_traffic_sum,story_group_exposure,entity_sentiment,event_sentiment,story_sentiment,story_group_sentiment_avg,story_group_sentiment_stdev,entity_name,entity_ticker,entity_exchange,entity_relevance,entity_country,entity_indices,entity_industry,entity_region,entity_sector,entity_competitors,entity_type,entity_composite_figi,entity_exch_code,entity_figi,entity_market_sector,entity_security_description,entity_security_type,entity_share_class_figi,entity_unique_id,entity_unique_id_fut_opt,entity_author_republish_score,entity_author_timeliness_score,entity_source_republish_score,entity_source_timeliness_score,event,event_group,event_relevance,event_author_republish_score,event_author_timeliness_score,event_source_republish_score,event_source_timeliness_score,event_impact_pct_change_avg,event_impact_pct_change_stdev,event_impact_pos,event_impact_neg,event_impact_gt_mu_add_sigma,event_impact_lt_mu_sub_sigma,event_impact_gt_mu_pos_add_sigma_pos,event_impact_lt_mu_neg_sub_sigma_neg,event_impact_gt_mu_pos_add_2sigma_pos,event_impact_lt_mu_neg_sub_2sigma_neg,event_impact_gt_1pct_pos,event_impact_lt_1pct_neg,overall_source_timeliness_score,overall_source_republish_score,overall_author_republish_score,overall_author_timeliness_score,harvested_at
>   5a431613914455535dd2f7e3,59a8c0cb631131661f7cca72,629355b4-5ef4-45ab-872a-9fd1809ca49d,f,552,hW9kPL6pMO0suREcwfIObD7SjwY=,A/mu8VqEc7agwge3hbjXgdFfDeA=,news,broadcastengineering.com,,11548,308325207322,high,31.2,33.35,31.2,36.9,38.9,Sony
>   Corp Ord,SNE,NYSE,100,N/A,[],Consumer
>   Electronics/Appliances,N/A,Consumer
>   Non-Durables,"[""MSFT"",""IBM"",""INTC"",""4331"",""NOKIA"",""HPQ"",""DIS"",""MSI"",""AAPL"",""PHG""]",US_EQUITY,BBG000BT7ZK6,UN,BBG000BT81N7,Equity,SNE,ADR,BBG001S5W6H8,EQ0010136500009000,,0,70.2,0.9566,40.4852,Employment
>   Actions - General,Employment
>   Actions,50.8,,,0,32.5118,,,,,,,,,,,,,53.7511,0.53,0,64.2908,2013-08-01T00:00:03.000Z

Could you tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) 'The order is same to my table but not same to csv file.'-Make the order same then whats the purpose of using csv import?
 use this-

```
load data local infile 'mycsv.csv' into table mytable fields terminated by ',' enclosed by ' ' lines terminated by '\n'
```

2) still want to ignore columns-
From Mysql docs:

You can also discard an input value by assigning it to a user variable and not assigning the variable to a table column:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.txt'  
INTO TABLE t1 (column1, @dummy, column2, @dummy, column3);
```

3)to skip first row- use Ignore 1 lines

Comment: What if I want to ignore some column in the csv? and should I ignore first row?

Comment: check the answer

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html)

> You must also specify a column list if the order of the fields in the
>   input file differs from the order of the columns in the table.
>   Otherwise, MySQL cannot tell how to match input fields with table
>   columns.

In other words, your column list must match the order in the CSV file for this to work.

To ignore columns within the csv you would assign them to a variable in your column list and then not do any further processing on them. If your csv has 4 columns and you only want the first and third columns the column list would look like

`(first_col, @dummy, third_col, @dummy)`

In your case, you can copy the header line and change any column name you don't want into the word @dummy.

You'll also be wanting to add `IGNORE 1 LINES` directly before your column list so that you can skip over the first row with the column names.

Comment: What if I want to ignore some column in the csv? If the name in csv and table is different, which one should I use?

Comment: You should have followed the link I posted and you'd have seen that eventuality is covered directly below the part I quoted. You can skip over columns by assigning them to variables within your column list (the example gives @dummy as a suitable var name), you then just ignore them. I'll update my answer to make that clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Some times you may need to use 'COLUMNS TERMINATED BY' instead 'FIELDS TERMINATED BY'