# Is there anyway to write a linux script that reads the csv file and create the sql file?

Tags: linux

I want to write a script that reads the csv file and create the sql file?
So I have several data in file.csv files like:

```
Ball,Jamin,1414 Willow Rd.,Cupertino,CA,94024
Church,Joe,2500 Main St.,Los Altos,CA,94023
Foothill,Ann,12345 El Monte Rd.,Los Altos,CA,94022
```

And I want to write a code in Linux to get the csv file like above and create the file.sql code so I can use that sql file for insert purpose.
For example, I want the code will be like this in .sql file

```
INSERT INTO students (lname,fname,address,city,state,zip) VALUES
('Ball', 'Jamin',  '1414 Willow Rd.',  'Cupertino',  'CA',  '94024');
INSERT INTO students (lname,fname,address,city,state,zip) VALUES
('Church', 'Joe',  '2500 Main St.', 'Los Altos',  'CA',  '94023');
INSERT INTO students (lname,fname,address,city,state,zip) VALUES
('Foothill', 'Ann', '12345 El Monte Rd.',  'Los Altos', 'CA',  '94022');
```

So for example, I say,

```
./generateSQL.sh file.csv
```

and it will generate and (create) and save the .sql file.
Is it possible?

Here is what I have done so far:

```
awk -F',' '{ print "insert into " $1 " VALUES(" $2 ", " $3 ", " $4 ", " $5 ", "  $6 ", " $7 ");" }' input.csv > output.log
```

My Code is only works for first line and I actually want this happen till all lines generated to SQL and I want this as a Generate.sh file that I can do below in my Linux. Not sure how:

```
./generateSQL.sh file.csv
```

Comment: Yes, there is a way. Does your CSV really have these empty lines as shown here? Also, are there any cells containing a `,`? If so, how is the `,` quoted?

Comment: Oh sorry, It does not have the empty lines. I can make sure all csv files are without empty lines and spaces

Comment: A shell script is not a robust solution for this. Have you considered checking whether your database allows importing CSV files by itself? Here's an [example for MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605765/importing-a-csv-into-mysql-via-command-line/6605783)

Comment: This maybe helps :https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/160360-read-csv-file-generate-sql-output.html

Comment: @thatotherguy We are doing that too, But I want to modify this insert in future (after I find the solution for this part)

Comment: @Socowi Thanks for fixing the question and none of the cells also have any `,`

Comment: **Beware** — CSV format is much more [complicated](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180#section-2) than you think it is. If you have a well-defined subset of CSV files you'll be working on, that's one thing; if you have to accept any arbitrary CSV file that's a much bigger task.

Comment: @StephenP I Undestand and Thanks for letting me know the problem. I will make sure the file will be always exact same format as above

Comment: To answer your question, yes there is a way. You should state the database. Some databases can parse CSV files. For example, [How to import CSV file to MySQL table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3635166/608639).

Comment: @jww Yes, I am using that too. But the purpose of this is something different. I like to modify the insert and call some SPs after I find the solution, So this is not only a insert statement.

Answer (score 0):

Bash loop

```
while IFS=',' read -r lname fname address city state zip; do
    printf "INSERT INTO students (lname,fname,address,city,state,zip) VALUES\n"
    printf "('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', %s');\n" "$lname" "$fname" "$address" "$city" "$state" "$zip"
done <<EOF
Ball,Jamin,1414 Willow Rd.,Cupertino,CA,94024
Church,Joe,2500 Main St.,Los Altos,CA,94023
Foothill,Ann,12345 El Monte Rd.,Los Altos,CA,94022
EOF
```

Slow, but flexible.

Awk script

```
awk -F',' '{ 
    print "INSERT INTO students (lname,fname,address,city,state,zip) VALUES"
    print "('\''" $1 "'\'', '\''" $2 "'\'', '\''" $3 "'\'', '\''" $4 "'\'', '\''"  $5 "'\'', '\''" $6 "'\'');" }' <<EOF
Ball,Jamin,1414 Willow Rd.,Cupertino,CA,94024
Church,Joe,2500 Main St.,Los Altos,CA,94023
Foothill,Ann,12345 El Monte Rd.,Los Altos,CA,94022
EOF
```

Faster, but external tool with it's own syntax. Also quoting here is pain, but it can be reduced by having the script as an awk script with awk shebang:

```
cat <<'EOF' >script.awk
#!/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
    FS=","
}
{
    print "INSERT INTO students (lname,fname,address,city,state,zip) VALUES"
    print "('" $1 "', '" $2 "', '" $3 "', '" $4 "', '"  $5 "', '" $6 "');"
}
EOF

chmod +x script.awk

./script.awk <<EOF
Ball,Jamin,1414 Willow Rd.,Cupertino,CA,94024
Church,Joe,2500 Main St.,Los Altos,CA,94023
Foothill,Ann,12345 El Monte Rd.,Los Altos,CA,94022
EOF
```